# Accessin ng-options variable in ng-change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

Seemingly simple issue here. I have an ng-options select tag that's working funky.

Basically my ng-change function does not work properly, as the first parameter, "v", is undefined. Any help?

```
<select ng-model="d.sub_customer" ng ng-options="v.description as v.description for v in subCustomers" ng-change="updateCustomer(v,d.id)"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the iteration variable in `ng-options` expression outside (unlike `ng-repeat`). Because ng-options just uses that expression and draws the options for the select in DOM. It really does not create a scope to keep hold off these properties, which is why it is unlike ng-repeat. In your case `d.sub_customer` will be the selected `v.description`,so you could just pass in that in the ng-change, i.e

```
  ng-change="updateCustomer(d.description,d.id)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="d.sub_customer" ng ng-options="v.description as v.description for v in subCustomers" ng-change="updateCustomer(v,d.sub_customer)"></select>
```